# Ajax passing null values to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

My "formAll" form must be received by the POST GetMember () method of my Members controller.
This method receives in parameter my model which is supposed to be sent by the ajax request.

The problem is that when I debug on my web browser, ajax correctly serializes my form and seems to send it correctly to the GetMember () method, but the metode receives the model that contains values that are all null. ..

It worked before and I actually made some changes (I changed the model) but I think I did it correctly ...

PS: I have deliberately deleted part of the form to avoid certain lines that have no added value to my question.

Do you have an idea?

```
@model IEnumerable<jak.formulaire.Models.MemberViewModel>

@if (Model != null)
{
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

            @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formAll", style = "margin-top:3%" }))
            {
                <div id="formMember">
                    <div style="margin-bottom:5%;margin-left:5%; margin-top:-2%"><h4>Personnal</h4></div>

                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-check-inline col-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Member_NameFirst, "Politeness", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Member_Politeness, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter politeness", @id = "Member_Politeness" } })
                        @*<small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>*@
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Member_Politeness, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Member_NameFirst, "First name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Member_NameFirst, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter first name", @id = "Member_NameFirst" } })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Member_NameLast, "Last name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Member_NameLast, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter last name", @id = "Member_NameLast" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-check-inline col-12" style="margin-top:1%">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Company_Website, "Website", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Company_Website, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter website", @id = "Company_Website" } })
                    </div>
                    <br /><br /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-12" style="text-align:right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEditMember">Submit</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <div style="margin-top:2%">
        <p>An error has occurred, please log out, close your browser completely and try again.</p>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            hideCPY();
            Edit();
        });

        function hideCPY() {
            $('#formCPY').hide();
            $('#formMember').show();
        }

        function hideMember() {
            $('#formMember').hide();
            $('#formCPY').show();
        }

        function Edit() {

            $(function () {
                $("#formAll").submit(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var formData = $("#formAll").serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://localhost:44338/Members/GetMember/",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data === "success") {
                                alert("Member successfully modified");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert('An error occurs during the process of your request');
                        }
                    });
                })
            });
        }
    </script>
}




[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMember(MemberViewModel model)
{
    ViewBag.sessionv = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("idMember");
    if (ViewBag.sessionv == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        FileMakerRestClient client = new FileMakerRestClient("https://fms171.hostmy.solutions", "helloJAK", userName, password);


        var toCreate = new MemberViewModel
        {
            Member_NameFirst = model.Member_NameFirst,
            Member_NameLast = model.Member_NameLast,
            Member_Politeness = model.Member_Politeness,
            Member_Mail = model.Member_Mail,
            Member_JobTitle = model.Member_JobTitle,
            Member_JobDepartment = model.Member_JobDepartment,
            Member_Phone = model.Member_Phone,
            Member_MobilePhone = model.Member_MobilePhone,
            Member_Fax = model.Member_Fax,
            Member_Skype = model.Member_Skype,
            Member_Twitter = model.Member_Twitter,
            //Member_NewsletterInt = Convert.ToInt32(model.Member_Newsletter),
            //Member_VegetarianInt = Convert.ToInt32(model.Member_Vegetarian),
            //Member_AuthorizeInt = Convert.ToInt32(model.Member_Authorize),
            Company_Address = model.Company_Address,
            Company_City = model.Company_City,
            Company_Country = model.Company_Country,
            Company_Fax = model.Company_Fax,
            Company_Name = model.Company_Name,
            //Company_NoHolderInt = Convert.ToInt32(model.Company_NoHolder),
            Company_Telephone = model.Company_Telephone,
            Company_Website = model.Company_Website,
            Company_Zip = model.Company_Zip,
            Company_VAT = model.Company_VAT

        };
        var mappedItem = _mapper.Map<Models.Members>(toCreate);
        mappedItem.Member_VegetarianInt = Convert.ToInt32(toCreate.Member_Vegetarian);
        mappedItem.Member_AuthorizeInt = Convert.ToInt32(toCreate.Member_Authorize);
        mappedItem.Member_NewsletterInt = Convert.ToInt32(toCreate.Member_Newsletter);
        mappedItem.Company_NoHolderInt = Convert.ToInt32(toCreate.Company_NoHolder);
        var results = await client.EditAsync(ViewBag.sessionv,mappedItem);

        return Ok();
    }
    else return BadRequest();
}






 public class MemberViewModel
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "member_nameFirst")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_NameFirst { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_nameLast")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_NameLast { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_politeness")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_Politeness { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_jobTitle")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_JobTitle { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_jobDepartment")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_JobDepartment { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_phone")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_Phone { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_mobile")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_MobilePhone { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_fax")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_Fax { get; set; }

        public bool Member_Vegetarian { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_vegetarian")] // the filemaker field to use
        public int Member_VegetarianInt { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_twitter")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_Twitter { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_skype")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_Skype { get; set; }

        public bool Member_Authorize { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_authorize")] // the filemaker field to use
        public int Member_AuthorizeInt { get; set; }

        public bool Member_Newsletter { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_newsletter")] // the filemaker field to use
        public int Member_NewsletterInt { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_zkp")] // the filemaker field to use
        public int Member_Zkp { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_mail")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_Mail { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "zkp_WEB")] // the filemaker field to use
        public int Member_Zkp_WEB { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "member_picture")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Member_Picture { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "company_name")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Company_Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "company_address")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Company_Address { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "company_zip")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Company_Zip { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "company_city")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Company_City { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "company_country")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Company_Country { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "company_vat")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Company_VAT { get; set; }

        public bool Company_NoHolder { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "company_noHolder")] // the filemaker field to use
        public int Company_NoHolderInt { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "company_telephone")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Company_Telephone { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "company_fax")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Company_Fax { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "company_website")] // the filemaker field to use
        public string Company_Website { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `$("#formAll").serialize()` ?

Comment: formData = "item.Member_Politeness=test&item.Member_NameFirst=testAA&item.Member_NameLast=test&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8EWivCW8E81LkK7l6nGp1o1rvc3q3AG4xwqqtx35ntoc6tVkkQ1K0Oul8d6k3OSIm423GCYSR-lbZotk3l8BWDBTMicFXwxGVKp7z7XW1UHG4R2ORQj4lvURurD7DmXK7eqfFHIOxPAULy-TbU8Qe5felTXhpe7TiCW7LHScQ87dDsVYca8PPziqaPxpgVmGXg&item.Member_Vegetarian=false&item.Member_Newsletter=false&item.Member_Authorize=false&item.Company_NoHolder=false"
Smth like this (i had to delete a part of it because it was too long lol)

Comment: Change `url: "https://localhost:44338/Members/GetMember/"` to `url: this.action`  and try again.

Comment: Not working, it keep boucling with in jquery but never reach my method.

Comment: you are doing a foreach on each item in the model. This will give you multiple forms with the same id. By the time Submit is pressed, So it will not know which one to send. I think you need to add `$(this)` to your assignment

Comment: Hmm i tried with $(this) but it does not work, could you tell me exactly where should i put it? Maybe i did wrong.

Comment: Figured out how to solve it! Im not using a IEnumerable anymore, i did results.tolist().first() and in my view @using Membersviewmodel! Thx for your help.